# scrape sentences from text to get all sentence separately stored in some data structure

Tags: c++

I want to get senteces from text. Text is full of paragraphs and `!`, `.` Or any other line seperator. Using regex I could do it but want it without regext library. Is there any C++ class which seperates sentences?

Otherwise another step is to compare each character with line seperating charater. But I dont know how to do it with vector. Any help is appreciated.

Here it goes with regex

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
  /* Input. */
  std::string input = "Here is a short sentence. Here is another one. And we say \"this is the final one.\", which is another example.";

  /* Define sentence boundaries. */
  boost::regex re("(?: [\\.\\!\\?]\\s+" // case 1: punctuation followed by whitespace
                  "|   \\.\\\",?\\s+"   // case 2: start of quotation
                  "|   \\s+\\\")",      // case 3: end of quotation
           boost::regex::perl | boost::regex::mod_x);

  /* Iterate through sentences. */
  boost::sregex_token_iterator it(begin(input),end(input),re,-1);
  boost::sregex_token_iterator endit;

  /* Copy them onto a vector. */
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  std::copy(it,endit,std::back_inserter(vec));

  /* Output the vector, so we can check. */
  std::copy(begin(vec),end(vec),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,"\n"));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a brute force approach ... I hope I understood correctly your request ...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "Here is a short sentence. Here is another one. And we say \"this  is the final one.\", which is another example.";
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> sentences;
    std::string current;
    while(i < input.length())
    {
        current += input[i];

        if(input[i] == '"')
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            while( j < input.length() && input[j] != '"')
            {
                current += input[j];
                j ++;
            }
            current += input[j];
            i = j + 1;
        }

        if(input[i] == '.' || input [i] == '!' || input[i] == '?')
        {
            sentences.push_back(current);
            current = "";
        }
        i ++;
    }

    for(i =0; i<sentences.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " -> " << sentences[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Obviously it needs more refinement, such as removing multiple spaces, etc...